# Want to compile only if statement in if-else

Tags: c++, ros

I am working on a project which should have to run on both ros melodic (ubuntu 18.04) and ros noetic(ubuntu 20.04). so while doing so I made an if-else statement in my code that,

```
if(distro=="noetic"){
    ...do this
else
    ...do this
```

The problem occurs basically, noetic and melodic support different versions of Point cloud Libraries(PCL) which also make them different in their way of initialization. So when I put PCL initialization (the way noetic support) in the if statement and in the else statement I put melodic way of initialization. I want the compiler( catkin_make command I use) to compile only the if statement but it also compiles else statement which gives an error because noetic did not support a melodic way of initialization. What should be the way?

Comment: Given the differences in the PCL dependency, if you want to support both melodic and noetic you shouldn't try to do this via the compiler. The standard ROS way to solve this is having a separate Melodic and Noetic branch.

Comment: Other stuff aside, this may be a good use case for `if constexpr (...)`, although that may not prevent the compiler from “fact-checking” the other branch. Maybe you could extract the initialization into a separate templated function and use [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) (either via `std::enable_if` or using a `decltype(something)` return value where `something` only makes sense in one of the two libraries) to filter out the overload / specialization that does not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use preprocessor macros. This needs to be handled before compile time. The preprocessor macros `#ifdef` and `#ifndef` will check if a token is present in the symbol table (check the documentation for your OS to see if there is a defined token for it), and skip to the according if/else section.

```cpp
#ifdef NOETIC_DISTRO
//Code for noetic distro
#endif
#ifdef OTHER_DISTRO
//Code for other distro
#endif
```

Comment: I don't think any ROS header files will actually define anything like "NOETIC_DISTRO". Although you could manually define them, I think the proper solution is to use the "ROS_VERSION_*" defines that exist in ros/common.h: https://answers.ros.org/question/9562/how-do-i-test-the-ros-version-in-c-code/